# About Dhanwantari Gayatri Mantra and water

Tags: gayatri-mantra

I am referring to this book: [Исцеляющие мантры в Аюрведе](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%98%D1%81%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8B%20%D0%B2%20%D0%90%D1%8E%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%20amazon&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwim0ZSa_fnrAhVBPZoKHSgvAXYQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=%D0%98%D1%81%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8B%20%D0%B2%20%D0%90%D1%8E%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%20amazon&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQA1CUwwJYk-sCYOLsAmgFcAB4AIABQYgB0AWSAQIxM5gBAKABAaoBC2d3cy13aXotaW1nwAEB&sclient=img&ei=JXhoX-aqCsH66ASo3oSwBw&bih=1214&biw=1598&client=firefox-b-d&hl=en#imgrc=DqFRlz54pl_GEM)

It is said, that according to Swami Sadashiva Tirtha if Dhanwantari Gayatri Mantra is chanted 21 times over the water, it becomes elixir, capable of healing most severe ailments.

My question is should the Mantra be chanted aloud (vachika japa) or mental chanting (mansika japa)? Is is also said that mansika japa is 10 time more effective then vachika japa, but is it OK for water?

Thank you!

Comment: You can do the japa in any way you want. But you have to touch the water pot (while you are chanting) with your right hand (fingers). This is one of the Abhimantrana methods.

Comment: Dear Rickross - can I hold mala then in left hand while chanting Mantra (to get the right number of Mantra repetition, e.g. 21), since right is occupied by touching water? Thanks!

Comment: Yes you have to do it coz there is no other options here.. sorry for the delay in the reply. I was off from this site for many days.